# I have a friend who got written up at work for behavoral issues.

Tags: communication

This is the actual write up: Employee A while working mentioned to Employee B that today was the 1 year anniversary of her daughters death.  Employee B said that she had heard the story and quickly moved on to business.  She made employee A cry.

I have never heard of such a thing.  Two things crossed my mind - Employee B was in an awkward position not knowing what to say that would not upset the other employee.  And Employee A is in a sensitive state.

Is this really deserving of a write up?

Comment: Who got the write up? Employee A or B?

Comment: Wether or not a business policy or process is fair or not is not something we can really answer.   We do not have all of the context and do not know the situation anyway so we really are not in a position to be a good judge.

Comment: Everyone needs to know what to say to an employee who is grieving.  It is too late to try to figure it out after you have the encounter.  When it first happens a simple," I am so sorry" is usually enough. When it is later like this, you cay something like, "That's difficult, I know the anniversaries are tough. Do you want to talk about it?" Or "Are you Ok?  We can reschedule for later if you like."  Employee B's response was extremely cruel. It basically discounted Employee A's grief.

Comment: It's worth knowing that if B's somewhere on the Asperger's spectrum, empathizing -- and realizing that they're expected to at least feign sympathy -- may be difficult for them.

Comment: When a person gets written up for something unusual or unexpected, there is almost always something else going on.  Even if the employee thinks the writeup is unfair, he or she needs to understand that the boss is unhappy with probably many things and adjust behavior accordingly.

Comment: @HLGEM I'm not I get "extremely cruel" from what is written above. "Extremely cruel" requires intent, and I don't see it. There is missing information, for sure. I also disagree with the statement "She made employee A cry." I'm sure Employee A was in a fragile state where it wouldn't take much for her to break out crying.

Comment: Hi Nikki, as you might have noticed, your question has attracted a lot of confusion/questions - are you able to [edit] and clarify a bit?

Comment: @nikki I've never heard such a thing myself.

Comment: @Mahair, extremely cruel does not require intent.

Answer (score 3):

That's pretty much up to whoever wrote employee B up. Obviously they deemed it serious enough. And in terms of morale it could well be, especially if it was a snub in front of others who were all feeling tender-hearted at the time.

In terms of general fairness, it's not possible to answer. Is it fair for employee A to project her personal grief onto others in the workplace and put them in an awkward position? Is employee A in the habit of 'fishing' for sympathy or sharing her life? Is employee B the sort of person who has demonstrated a dislike of being drawn into such conversations. Is there an underlying issue with both or either?

I think it was probably in bad taste but only some managers would deem it worthy of a writeup on the information given. Other managers would have let it slide, and perhaps reprimanded employee B slightly, or even sent employee home to deal with her grief. No way of knowing how individuals would react.

Comment: You forgot another possibility. If employee A complained that employee B was "insensitive" to her story, then HR would have to write a report but it doesn't necessarily mean someone got into trouble. Saying you heard the story of someone's lost doesn't really show negative or positive remarks and as you said can be taken any way depending on the person.

Comment: I agree, a forced write up because of a complaint is also a possibility